# How can I send a POST request without data in Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, mongoose

So I am already using Ajax to send an array to the router as you could see here...

```
 var send = function () {
            var data = search
            console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/next",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Success')
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
        }
        send();
```

If I console.log this as

```
console.log(req.body)
```

I get

```
[ 'Faye Dunaway', 'Kathy Bates' ]
```

which is fine, I need this. However, in my router I am also trying to render a new page with data in it like this....

```
router.post("/next", function (req, res) {
    Movies.find({name:{ $in: req.body}}, function(err, found){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('movies',{
                movies:found
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Now I have been told that I can not call res.render with  ajax so I needed to make a button inside a form.

```
<form action="/next" method="post">
    <button  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg next">next</button>
 </form>
```

However, if I console.log req.body now i get

```
[ 'Faye Dunaway', 'Kathy Bates' ]
{}
```

So I am thinking 2 things, either res.render has to be called with ajax or I need to get rid of the {}. As you can tell I am new to this. Thank your for your help. Ask for any additional information.

Comment: the problem is you are getting two http requests..one with required data and other with empty body. Is that the problem?

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi Yes, I guess you could say that. But I need ajax to send the array and I also need the form button too to trigger the res.render since that can't be done with ajax. But because of that I have an empty object that keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Can you please check the outputs for `console.log(req.url)` and tel me...

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi Sorry for the lateness, the output for req.url is /next both for Ajax and button.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, data passed on render is not in body but used in templating engine. So you can access it inside script block of your templating engine (PUG) like this.

```
script.
    !{movies}
```

If you want to access the data throught bundled script (created with webpack) , you have to define it in templating like this.

```
script.
    const movies = !{movies}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have problem accessing the data in in res.render how ever, req.body has an array and and and empty object. I am trying to get rid of the empty object.

Comment: ah, i see. Sorry, i  wrongly intrepeted your question.